# Reset SelectableLabel in kivy

Tags: kivy

ScreenTest is a screen with:
- A view with selectable labels
- A Label that changes dependant on the selected label
- A reset button

The reset button is supposed to reset the selection made in the view, but I do not know how to the selected SelectableLabel and then set its "is_selected" to False. There is no id or class I could access to change this parameter
What I need is that, through clicking the reset button, nothing in the view is selected and therefore no text is shown in the Label (or the text is reset to "" as text_selected is empty).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""

<ScreenTest>:
    BoxLayout:
        TestView:
            id: test_view

        Label:
            id: text_lbl
            text: "" if not test_view.text_selected else test_view.text_selected 


        Button:
            id: reset_btn
            on_press: print("Wow")


<TestView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    text_selected: ''
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        id: culture_sub_view_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
""")


class TestView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data =  [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "Test1.text"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "Test2.text"},
            {"text": "Test3", "description": "Test3.text"}
        ]


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
            rv.text_selected = rv.data[index]['description']
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class ScreenTest(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(ScreenTest(name='menu'))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


test_app = TestApp()
test_app.run()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick solution

I believe the simplest method would be to iterate over elements within the recycle box, deselect them if they were selected and set the text to `""`. Consider a following function declared within your `TestView` class:

```
def remove_selection(self):
    # Remove text
    self.parent.children[1].text = ""

    # Remove selection
    for child in self.children[0].children:
        if child.selected:
            child.selected = False
```

Naturally, you have to call it when the button is pressed, you can change your layout to:

```
Button:
    id: reset_btn
    on_press: test_view.remove_selection()
```

## Slightly better way

Calls to children and parents can get quite messy in more complex layouts, so I'd like to suggest a cleaner way to solve your problem. Since you only handle 1 selected item at a time, I think the best approach would be to store the item itself within your program and retrieve information from it when needed. Precisely, instead of storing `name_selected` and `text_selected` in your `test_view`, you could simply store the selected item. To do that, a number of changes have to be introduced:

1. Import `ObjectProperty` and `StringProperty`:

   ```
   from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
   ```
2. Add a `selected` attribute to your `TestView` class, allowing `None` will help to check if anything is selected at all:

   ```
   class TestView(RecycleView):
       selected = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)
   ```
3. Edit `remove_selection` method I've mentioned above:

   ```
   def remove_selection(self):
       # Remove selection
       if self.selected is not None:
           self.selected.selected = False
           self.selected = None
   ```
4. Add `text_selected` and `name_selected` properties to the `SelectableLabel` class:

   ```
   class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
       index = None
       selected = BooleanProperty(False)
       selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
       text_selected = StringProperty()
       name_selected = StringProperty()
   ```
5. Edit `apply_selection` method:

   ```
   def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
       self.selected = is_selected
       if is_selected:
           print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
           # Store selected text and name inside the label
           self.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
           self.text_selected = rv.data[index]['description']
           # Remember the selection
           rv.selected = self
       else:
           print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
   ```
6. Change the text displayed in your `text_lbl`:

   ```
   Label:
       id: text_lbl
       text: "" if test_view.selected is None else test_view.selected.text_selected
   ```
7. Remove not needed properties (`text_selected`, `name_selected`) from `<TestView>`:

   ```
   <TestView>:
       viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
   ```